# New Google reCAPTCHA JavaScript namespace callback

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, captcha

We're trying to implement the new Google reCAPTCHA on our website, however when we try and load a callback from it using a namespaced function, the callback does not run.

Changing the callback to not use a callback works correctly. We're doing something similar with the Google Maps API, which works fine.

Is there any way to get around this, or is this a limitation of the new Google reCAPTCHA system?

**Code**

```
<script>
    var namespace = {};
    namespace.captcha = function() {
        alert("Hello world!")
    };
</script>
<script src="//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=namespace.captcha&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

The issue really is that we want to keep all our code wrapped up in namespaced scripts using revealing modular pattern. A way around this is to create a global variable and use this as the callback, but it's not quit what I had hoped for.

**Global callback**

```
<script>
    var namespace = {};
    namespace.captcha = (function() {         
        function call() {
            alert("Hello world!")
       };
       window.callback = namespace.captcha.call;   
       return call:call;
    })();
</script>
<script src="//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=callback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

Comment: Yes, it looks like they don't allow it.

Comment: "Changing the callback to not use a callback works correctly" Did you mean to not use a namespace?

Comment: I'm having same problem PLUS the issue that we minify function names, so our global namespace function names are unpredictable.

Comment: What is the problem with using 
<script src="//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=namespace.captcha.call&render=explicit" async defer></script>

Comment: I also can't get recaptcha V2 to work with a namespace'd module function as a callback.

Comment: Should that be call:call or call.call?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using the [Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#js_api) to set the callback.

This will allow you to use the namespaced callback, or even the scope protected callback when using a framework.

I couldn't test it, so as an example:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');

script.id = 'container'
script.src = '//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit';
script.async = true;
script.defer = true;

script.onload = () => { ... };

document.body.appendChild(script);
```

## For the V3

Your `script.onload` function could be like:

```
grecaptcha.ready(function() {
  namespace.captcha();
});
```

## For the V2

Your `script.onload` function could be like:

```
grecaptcha.render('container', { 
  callback: namespace.captcha
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The file api.js load another stuff.

The parameter onload=functionCallback in:

//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=callback&render=explicit

is used to determinate the function that will be loaded when the stuff in the api.js is loaded.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).